# AWS Lambda To Atlas

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to connect my Lambda function to Mongo Atlas. It was all working fine but I needed to move my function inside a VPC so I could use redis.

Now I cannot connect to my database.
I looked at the security group on the VPC and added the mongo db port but with no joy

Also - the mongo IP Whitelist is as follows for now
0.0.0.0/0 (includes your current IP address)

Is there anything else I should try?

Thank you

Comment: Can you confirm if your database and Lambda function are in the same VPC?

Comment: The mongo db is on Mongo Atlas so it is external to Amazon. Well its potentially hosted on Amazon but as far as we are concerned, it is a third party tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I needed to move my function inside a VPC so I could use redis.

If you are:

- Using dedicated MongoDB Atlas instances (i.e. not shared instances M0, M2 and M5 clusters).
- And, the MongoDB Atlas deployment is hosted on AWS

Then, you could follow this instruction to [set up VPC peering connection](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-vpc-peering/#set-up-vpc-peering-connection).

Please note that MongoDB Atlas supports VPC peering with other AWS VPCs in the **same region**. AWS does not support cross-region VPC peering. For multi-region clusters, you must create VPC peering connections per-region.

See also the tutorial shown on: [Introducing VPC peering to MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-vpc-peering-for-mongodb-atlas)

Answer (score 0):

struggled for days 
using this tutorial
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-vpc-peering-for-mongodb-atlas

but it work in the end, when i found a missing step in the tutorial; when i used default VPC.

When crating custom VPC, rout table, and subnet; the subnet was what got me... auto assign IP needs to be enabled on the subnet;

PS you need at least two subnets for Lambda, so create one more if you haven't