# mongodb atlas + aws lambda cannot setup security whitelist?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have been reading these few posts but they are a bit outdated so I just want to confirm if my understanding is correct up to date.

I am currently playing around with mongodb atlas and using the free tier only.
I am thinking of using aws lambda to periodically access mongodb to make a backup to s3.

To my understanding, I have to turn on `0.0.0.0` which I do not want to do at all because it'll be a bad idea if it's a production db though.
Through the readings and up to today.  If I don't want to add `0.0.0.0` into mongodb atlas whitelist I have to create a VPC in aws just for the lambda function right?
Also, free tiers at mongodb atlas does not support the connection?

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions to my understanding.

These are the posts I read

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-vpc-peering-for-mongodb-atlas

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/serverless-development-with-nodejs-aws-lambda-mongodb-atlas

[AWS Lambda To Atlas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50277533/aws-lambda-to-atlas)